# Nextjs 11.1.0 does not watch code changes in node_modules dir

Tags: javascript, webpack, next.js

Nextjs 11.1.0 does not watch code changes in `node_modules` dir while Nextjs 10.2.1 does watch code changes in `node_modules` dir.

At project with Nextjs 11.1.0 I have explicitly set watch options:

```
config.watchOptions.ignored = config.watchOptions.ignored.filter(
    ignore => !ignore.toString().includes('node_modules'),
)
```

Though, it does not make any difference. Rebuilding project `next build` does help but it takes too long to compile.

Answer (score -1):

Through trial and error I find a work-a-round. I get my changes at `/node_modules` folder recompiled after making any change and save at `babel.config.js`.

Comment: Which changes did you make to your Babel file?

Comment: any kind of changes, e.g a blank line